# session based multistep form cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp

Basically i have 3 forms.
I have one action in my form and i want create 3 steps form using session.
I want when i click the next button it validates the form1,if successful then redirects to form2..
like wise for form3 but keep all the data in session and in third step the action goes runs and add all the data to database.
I only need to check conditions from session before my insert goes run in my action addjob. 
Plz help me to do this.

My main question is how to get all the post data in one session variable and check step by step before insert..

i am learner in cakephp and i have not enough idea about session.
if you are a expert then plz do this.

```
 public function addjob($id = NULL) {   
    $this->layout = "layout_registration_old";        
    $this->loadcategory();
    $this->loadcargo(); 
   //$this->loadsubcategory(); 
    $this->getCountries(); 
    $this->getstates(); 
    if ($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post')) {          
        if (isset($id)) {
            $this->Job->id = $id;
        } else {
            $this->request->data['Job']['status'] = 1;  
            $this->request->data['Job']['job_type'] = 1; //this is used to update the job type private or public.
            $this->Job->create();
        }
        $this->Job->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Job->AddEdit()) { // ADDEdit is the validation name in model              
            if ($this->Job->save($this->request->data['Job'], false)) {
                if (isset($id)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Job has been updated sucessfully.'));

                } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Job has been added succesfully.'));

                }
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $errors = $this->Job->validationErrors;

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please check your entry.'), 'flash_error');
        }
    }
    if (isset($id)) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Job->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => base64_decode($id))));
    }

}
```

**form - 1**

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Job', array('url' => array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'addjob')));?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('customer_name',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('customer_no',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('customer_email',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
       <?php
                  echo $this->Form->input('transport_type', array(
                      'type' => 'select',
                      'label' => false,
                     'class' => 'select',
                      'options' => array(
                          1 => 'Road'
                      ),                

                  ));
              ?>
 <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class' => "navigation_button btn btn-primary btn-sm", 'div' => false)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**form - 2**

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Job', array('url' => array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'addjob')));?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->input('fname',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('lname',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
   <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
   <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class' => "navigation_button btn btn-primary btn-sm", 'div' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**form - 3**

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Job', array('url' => array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'addjob')));?>

     <?php echo $this->Form->input('shop',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->input('business',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('status',array('div' => false, 'label' => false));?>  
 <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class' => "navigation_button btn btn-primary btn-sm", 'div' => false)); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the data from first 2 forms in a session, you should implement a multi part form using any **javascript solution** (Form wizard). Validate the data of each step using javascript or via ajax (if needs to be done dynamically) before moving to the next step and **submit form at the end** so that you don't have to play with sessions.

[Example link](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-formvalidation.html)

PS - This could go as a comment to the question but I haven't gained enough reputations to post comments yet :(